# How to push array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to put data from Query into array, but this code is not working. can you explain the right way ? thanks

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM populasi WHERE blablabla";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$tampung = array();
foreach ($result as $m) {
    $tampung = array_push($tampung, "new google.maps.LatLng($m[x], $m[y]), ");
}
echo $tampung;
```

Comment: Read about [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) (Although it looks wrong overall I must say)

Comment: `array_push()` returns an integer so by doing `$tampung = array_push( ... )` you're reassigning `$tampung` to an `(int)` ... ditch the `$tampung = ` bit.

Comment: OR a simple `$tampung[] = "new google.maps.LatLng($m[x], $m[y]), "`

Comment: As manual suggests it is quicker if you are only adding one item to the array to use `$x[] = $y;` syntax over `array_push()` as you then dont need to call a function

Comment: Best way to push some element into your array is `$tampung[] = "new google.maps.LatLng($m[x], $m[y]),"`. This method is faster then using `array_push()`. To print array, please use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`.

If you want to print pretty formated array and you didn't installed `XDebug` use `echo <pre>; print_r($yourArrayHere);`.  This small construction will prettify array output and will help you to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
foreach ($result as $m) {
    $tampung[] = 'new google.maps.LatLng('.$m[x].', '.$m[y].')';
}
var_dump($tampung);
```

You can not echo array, use `var_dump($arr)` or `print_r($arr)` instead

Comment: We dont normally answer TYPO's we just make a simple comment and close the question as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You are just executing the query, you have not fetched it. 
Fetch it to an array first :

```
$data=$result->fetch_assoc();
```

than you can use array_push function

Comment: Assuming this is `mysqli` - the question never specifies what `$con` is so it *could* be a custom database wrapper where the `query()` method returns an iterable recordset ... unlikely but it could be.

Comment: To make a complete answer you really should also mention the other error i.e. the incorrect use of `array_push()`